# How to make the options in react-select dropdown accessible?

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, react-select

I am building a **reactjs** application and I am using a library called **react-select** for my dropdown which is searchable.
but the problem I am facing is that the options inside the select are **not being read out** by ***NVDA screenreader*** when using arrow keys.
and am not able to **set focus** on this dropdown as well for some reason.

I tried it via the official documentation but no luck as of now.

*The library I am using:*
**React-select**

https://react-select.com/home

*The code:*

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

export const flavourOptions = [
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla", rating: "safe" },
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate", rating: "good" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry", rating: "wild" },
  { value: "salted-caramel", label: "Salted Caramel", rating: "crazy" }
];

export default class SampleDropdown extends Component {
  state = {
    isClearable: true,
    isDisabled: false,
    isLoading: false,
    isRtl: false,
    isSearchable: true
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementById("translate").focus();
  }

  render() {
    const {
      isClearable,
      isSearchable,
      isDisabled,
      isLoading,
      isRtl
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Select
          className="basic-single"
          classNamePrefix="select"
          defaultValue={flavourOptions[0]}
          isDisabled={isDisabled}
          isLoading={isLoading}
          isClearable={isClearable}
          isRtl={isRtl}
          isSearchable={isSearchable}
          name="color"
          options={flavourOptions}
          id="translate"
        />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is a working example in codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-clarke-euk0e

**Actual result:** When I enter the page, the dropdown does not have the focus. and am not able to read out options in the dropdown using arrow keys in NVDA screenreader.the options are being read out as blank.

**Expected result:** When I enter the page, the dropdown should have the focus. and the options in the dropdown should be read out when using arrow keys when NVDA screenreader is switched on.

Comment: I guess you can follow this open issue and push for it https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3691

Comment: my options in the react-select seem to be reading out as "blank", the accessibility bug open for react-select seems to be for customizing the message for accessibility. so it seems to be a different bug.but Thank you for bringing this bug to my attention, Laura

Comment: I tried a demo in code sandbox and the options read out " blank", then it reads out as option focused. but I can't figure out why the option focused is not coming inside my project.

Comment: I don't have this issue on Voice Over app on any react-select component I have tried. All the options are well described. I suspect it's related on how you use yours inside your code not just the way you declare it like above.

Comment: hai Laura, Thanks for replying. I directly copy pasted the code from the code sandbox from above and it is still not working. but in code sandbox it works,(it reads out "blank",then option focused ) in NVDA. but when it is in my project , it doesnt read out option focused. it just reads blank. if you have any idea why this bug is occurring please let me know and thanks again

Answer (score 4):

I looked at using the same library but ran into accessibility issues as well. I ended up building my custom select element and manually handling the key presses, focus movement, and label announcements. If you're stuck on using react-select you'll probably need to amend it yourself or wait for a PR.

Otherwise, if you're up for the challenge, you can follow my tutorial on creating an [accessible select component in React.](https://medium.com/@Tnodes/creating-an-accessible-custom-select-component-in-react-982f2422fb9c) You can pull apart the code on [codesandbox as well](https://codesandbox.io/s/31440w1vo6). This might make it easier to port to the react-select as well.

And of course, I'd also recommend using the native select element, as that will handle accessibility best.

Comment: Thank you Taylor, for replying to this, but I want a searchable dropdown that is accessible, let me know if you find anything. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Reach UI has accessible components. This Combobox could be of use https://reach.tech/combobox